# SonarQube v5.6+ with Java plugin v42 Inconsistent Severity rating between summary and detail view

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

When analysing Java code the Issues view shows Severity but sometimes the Severity shown in the summary and detail (accessed via “…”) is different. I’m using the supplied rule base without modification and can’t understand why the Severity rating would be different in summary and detail. For example:

- Rules “"equals(Object obj)" should test argument type” scan report in summary view it marked as **Bug Blocker** but detail view (when you click the …) it shows as **Bug Minor** [please see the attached screenshot [SonarQubeIssue2.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnBqS.jpg))
- Rules “String literals should not be duplicated” scan report in summary view it marked as **Code Smell Minor** but detail view (when you click the …) it shows as **Code Smell Blocker** [please see the attached screenshot  [SonarQubeIssue1.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz8eh.jpg))

Environment Details:

- Server: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1
- SonarQube Version 5.6.3
- Java Plugin version 4.2
- Sonar-scanner version 2.7
- Java  version 1.8.0_91-b14
- Sonar Way Default Rules for Java
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express

I have ran on SonarQube 5.6.1 and 6.0 with Java-plugin 4.2 same issue persist. I was wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue and if you know the resolution. Thanks

Comment: can you check the history of the issue by clicking on the period « a day ago » (which will have changed) to confirm there were no manual action?

Comment: then, can you check the quality profile associated to your project, to check the severity of the rule hasn't been changed? what are the severities of this rules in your corresponding Quality Profile?

Comment: Thanks @Teryk for your response. Answer to your queries, 
<BR/> Answer to Q1. > There is no history as it was the first scan. 
<BR/> Answer to Q2. > I used **SonarWay Java** quality profile with default rule sets. I can see the same problem when I open the those two rules (S1192 & S2097) quality profile. Please see the screenshot via the image link ![S1192 & S2097](http://imgur.com/a/V6t7A)

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue, it is with the **SonarQube v5.6.+ Default Quality Profile SonarWay Java**. It seems to me, severity of  the rule in this profile does not reflect as Java-Plugin v4.2 severity.

**Solution:** There are several options,

- Create a new quality profile and add the rules from the java plugins available rule set
- Copy the SonarWay Profile and modify the rule's severity to match the Java-Plugin  v4.2 rules severity
- Modify all existing rules severity in the SonarWay Java default profile to reflect the java-plugin v4.2 severity

Answer (score 0):

[Restore built-in](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-MakesureI%27vegotalltherelevantnewrulesinmyprofile?) Quality Profile to have all the rules and updated severity of the last version of your plugin

Comment: Thanks for the better and the proper solution.

Comment: thanks, feel free to vote and accept the answer @SanjoyBanik